# What if regressor self correlated

Tags: regression, time-series, mathematical-statistics

I am wondering if the self-correlationess in X of the linear regression will impact the estimation or the t-statistics of the coefficient? For example, we have a linear regression model Y(t) = a1 + a2*X(t) where X(t) can be written as X(t) = M(t) + M(t-1) + M(t-2). we can assume Y(t) and M(t) are IID random variable. I am curious is the estimation a2 correct? and is the t-statistic of a2 correct?